# Android studio Error with FireBaseListAdapter

Tags: java, android

I'm making my first app on android studio and i got an error when i want to display a Chat Message because of FirebaseListadapter that request listoptions

This is the error

```
 error: constructor FirebaseListAdapter in class FirebaseListAdapter<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        private final FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
                                                                 ^
      required: FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage>
      found: Chat,Class<ChatMessage>,int,DatabaseReference
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
      where T is a type-variable:
```

And this is the part of the code that dosnt work

```
    private final FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
            R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {

        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };
```

I updated my dependencies and sync the app but stil dosnt work